# Force Windows 8.1 to run 'mstsc' even if an instance is already running

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1, multiple-instances

In Windows 8.1, if I already have a remote desktop session open I'm unable to open another one by doing the following, which works fine in Windows 7 -

> **Start** -> `mstsc` -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This is mighty inconvenient as it means I instead have to do this -

> **Start** -> `mstsc /v myserver.mydomain.com` -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> -> click on result

Is there a way around this at all? It seems that many MS programs, including Internet Explorer, have this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You can open another instance by middle-clicking the icon in the taskbar. Is that not easier?

Comment: @James did not know you could middle mouse to open a new instance. I have always right clicked. Thanks :)

Comment: @James - I did not know that, that does indeed make things easier. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't repro for me - that is, I'm able to run mstsc.exe and open a new connection to something. What's the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click the program in your toolbar then click the name of the application and it should start a new one. You can also right click the shortcut in the start menu and click "open in a new window"

Edit: Thanks James for mentioning you can middle mouse the program in the toolbar. I never knew this and will use this from now on!

Answer (score 4):

Start > mstsc > Shift+enter :)

Well, according to [This technet thread, anyway](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/e9fd8b8a-bc5f-48a8-9e18-6da070c0caec/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-the-same-application-from-the-metro-interface)

Comment: That does work, but it's a bit of a faff. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Much easier than the mouse related solutions IMO

Comment: Likewise.. must be the gamer in me

Answer (score 2):

You can also shift-click on the icon in the taskbar to open up a new instance of any application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy and universal solution that not many people know about: just use the middle mouse button to click on any program in your windows task bar. It will open another instance of this program. it works for Excel, MSTSC, WORD, Notepad, Internet Explorer, etc.